# Do...while is not working in input verification

Tags: java, setter

So I'm trying to do an input verification for my program in java, and I'm trying to do that in this setter:

```
  public void setClientName(String clientName) {
        boolean valid;
        do{
            valid = false;
            try{
                 if(clientName.matches("[a-zA-Z]+")){
                    this.clientName = clientName;
                 }else{
                     throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid client name");
                 }
            }catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("Invalid name");
                valid = true;
            }
        }while(!valid);
    }
```

But when I call it and put a wrong name, the do...while does not work and the program just continue

Here's where I call it

```
  public void openAccount(int i){
        nCartao = 2021120040 + i;
        System.out.println("Account Number : " + (nCartao));
        System.out.println("Client Name :");

        setClientName(sc.next()); // I CALL IT HERE

        System.out.println("Client Age : ");
        age = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Balance :");
        balance = sc.nextInt();
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you set `valid = true;` when the user inputs an invalid name?? That is very counterintuitive

Comment: You pass a string (the result of `sc.next()`) into your function and then loop until it's valid. But nothing in your method asks the user for new input (or changes `clientName`), so it's an infinite loop.
Also (and that's not the main problem) throwing an exception and catching it in the same method is almost always a bad idea. You could simply replace the `throw` statement with the content of the `catch` block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe that's because in your catch you are stating that `valid` is `true` when it should be `false` to repeat the block.